# Query JSON field in PostgreSQL

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I have a JSON field in my PostgreSQL database with JSON schema like this

```
{
   "home":{
      "lat":"37.774192",
      "long":"-92.118511",
      "address":"home address"
   },
   "work":{
      "lat":"37.774192",
      "long":"-92.118511",
      "address":"work address"
   },
   "more":[
      {
         "id":"bRuKnd",
         "name":"gym",
         "lat":"37.774192",
         "long":"-92.118511",
         "address":"gym address"
      },
      {
         "id":"eVdOlD",
         "name":"fastfood",
         "lat":"37.774192",
         "long":"-92.118511",
         "address":"fastfood addres"
      },
      {
         "id":"SwkfcL",
         "name":"Res",
         "lat":"37.774192",
         "long":"-92.118511",
         "address":"Res address"
      }
   ]
}
```

I can get each JSON field in "more" or "work" and "home" object with this query

```
UPDATE items FROM (SELECT loc FROM public.tbl_user where uuid = '2fa7a484-f454-4d44-94be-a4011aee47b4') as o 
   ,json_array_elements(o.loc#>'{more}') AS items where items->>'id' = 'eVdOlD' ;
```

I don't know how can I edit or delete these fields in my database

I need these queries

- edit the home object and delete its values
- edit work object and delete its values
- add edit and delete items on more object

Comment: You should consider normalizing your database, and perhaps start by extracting json data into tabular data. This will make it work faster, and make reads and updates trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you edit values in postgres JSON, you're not editing so much as replacing the row with something new.

jsonb_set is probably what you're looking for.

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

Based on a simpler form of your example:

```
sophia=> create table foo (bar jsonb);
CREATE TABLE
sophia=> insert into foo values ('{
   "home":{
      "lat":"37.774192",
      "long":"-92.118511",
      "address":"home address"
   }}'::jsonb);
INSERT 0 1
sophia=> select * from foo;
                                       bar                                       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"home": {"lat": "37.774192", "long": "-92.118511", "address": "home address"}}
(1 row)

sophia=> update foo set bar = jsonb_set(bar, '{home,address}', '"29 Acacia Road"');
UPDATE 1
sophia=> select * from foo;
                                        bar                                        
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"home": {"lat": "37.774192", "long": "-92.118511", "address": "29 Acacia Road"}}
(1 row)

sophia=>
```

And similarly for deletion:

```
sophia=> update foo set bar = jsonb_set(bar, '{home}', (bar -> 'home') - 'address');
UPDATE 1
sophia=> select * from foo;
                         bar                          
------------------------------------------------------
 {"home": {"lat": "37.774192", "long": "-92.118511"}}
(1 row)

sophia=>
```